# How to Close another Process from c#

Tags: c#, process, windows-media-encoder

I need to close another Process (Windows Media Encoder) from a C# Application ,and so far i can do it with:

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("wmenc.exe")[0].CloseMainWindow();
```

But if the Media Encoder Application is Streaming or Recording it shows a Dialog on exit:

> "Are you sure you want to stop encoding?"

So is there a way to answer or click Yes button from Code?

[Edit]
Many users are answering with `Process.kill()` ,but that is not an Option ,because `Process.Kill();` will Terminate **Windows Media Encoder** immediately ,and **Windows Media Encoder** will not Finalize the File which is Writing ,which forces me to Reindex the Video File .So no i cannot use Process.Kill();

Comment: Don't bother about closing any windows. Better look for ways to force the process be killed. What if it opened another window? The process won't quit if any of the associated windows is open

Comment: I believe the processes retrieved by GetProcessesByName should be disposed, BTW. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957320/what-does-process-dispose-actually-do

Comment: I'm not sure who closed this as a duplicate, but the questions have nothing to do with one another and this question is not answered in any way by the target question.

Answer (score 10):

```
Process[] runningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in runningProcesses)
{
    // now check the modules of the process
    foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules)
    {
        if (module.FileName.Equals("MyProcess.exe"))
        {
            process.Kill();
        } else 
        {
         enter code here if process not found
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Iterating through ProcessModule.filename triggered "**Access denied**" exception, however the following code worked fine.

```
Process[] runningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in runningProcesses)
{
    if (process.ProcessName == PROC_NAME)
        process.CloseMainWindow();
}
```

Comment: In some cases it's better than Kill - for example killing excel may corrupt opened file, CloseMainWindow has no such side effect