# How to get window handle of minimized window

Tags: .net, windows

I need to get window handle of minimized window in tray. I know process name, but it has not MainWindowHandle set because it is minimized. How do I get to know the window handle?

Comment: Why do you need a window handle of a process that is not showing a window?

Comment: I need to close the application with WM_CLOSE message - for that I need window handle.

Comment: The premise of the question is nonsensical, a process with a minimized main window certainly *does* have its MainWindowHandle property set.  Just try it with Notepad for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Close another Process from c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046916/how-to-close-another-process-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to close the main window to end the process, there's a pretty straightforward way of doing that using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` object. This example closes the first instance it finds of Notepad.

```
var procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
if (procs.Length > 0)
    procs[0].CloseMainWindow();
foreach (var proc in procs)
    proc.Dispose();
```